# GeoJSON conversion to GeoJSONL BigQuery load error

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, jq, data-analysis, geojson

I am trying to upload to BigQuery the geospatial data of community areas of Chicago. However, I am getting the following errors messages when trying to create a table from newline delimited geoJSON file:

> Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.

> Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0

> Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Nested arrays not allowed.

I obtained the data from [Chicago Data Portal](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Community-Areas-current-/cauq-8yn6) and [exported it in GeoJSON format](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lflbja65s0ve11xb2fuq7/cm.geojson?rlkey=8w7mcxm3o4dm8d33gqxz4t2z2&dl=0). I used jq to convert the GeoJSON to [newline delimited GeoJSON](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eswd7pnomn4kkgmnqafow/cm.gejsonl?rlkey=hmuo10eebok3g0b2csoti6jgf&dl=0) with jq like this:

```
type cm.geojson | jq -c ".features[]" > cm.geojsonl
```

What am I doing wrong & how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you loading the file using BigQuery web? I think it does not provide a way to specify geojson extension, so tries to load it as regular JSON-NL. The file itself seems fine.

Use "bq load" command, like 
`bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --json_extension=GEOJSON --autodetect tmp.cm cm.gejsonl `

Comment: That was the fix, thank you @MichaelEntin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment to the question by michael-entin provided the solution.

Switching from web console to bq load in the Cloud Shell Terminal did the trick.

```
bq load  --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
--json_extension=GEOJSON --autodetect \
my_dataset_name.my_new_table \
gs://cloud_storage_bucket/source.geojsonl \
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `cat` command, single quotes, and avoid using `.geojsonl` extension.  Just use the regular `.json`.

BigQuery [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#geojson-files) explain the procedure verbatim:

```
cat cm.geojson | jq -c '.features[]' > converted.json
```

If you convert the geojson exactly this way, it will load:

```
bq load \                                                                              
 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
 --json_extension=GEOJSON \
 --autodetect \
 geo-generalize:test.converted  converted.json

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT column_name FROM `geo-generalize.test.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WHERE table_name="converted";'

+-------------+
| column_name |
+-------------+
| shape_len   |
| comarea     |
| comarea_id  |
| area_numbe  |
| area_num_1  |
| perimeter   |
| area        |
| geometry    |
| shape_area  |
| community   |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious but I don't think the "cat" command works on Windows.